# Getting Windows Defender Status from WMI on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, c#, wmi

**Problem**: On windows 10 I query the WMI using C# at the namespace `Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender` for the class `MSFT_MpComputerStatus` to get useful information about the computer antivirus status ([see this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/defender/msft-mpcomputerstatus)). This is because from windows 8.1 to the most recent Windows that namespace exists as it can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyGID.png)

However, things don't work that way on Windows 7 because as it can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rCYF.png) the namespace `Root\Microsoft\Windows\Defender` does not exist.

**Question**: How do I programatically read the information equivalent to what is contained in class `MSFT_MpComputerStatus` if there's no such thing on up to Windows 7 ?